# Why does Pip seem to exclude itself from "pip freeze"?

Tags: python, pip

Trying to setup some simple automation around the requirements.txt and multiple machines and it looks like "pip" just doesn't include itself in the requirements.txt. Note that I have installed it in the same virtualenv via 'pip install pip --upgrade'.

```
$ which pip
/home/mallyvai/Code/src/bin/pip
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /home/mallyvai/Code/src/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip freeze | grep -i pip
Warning: cannot find svn location for flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405
$
```

Comment: Why would it? If you're installing from `requirements.txt`, you probably have `pip` installed already.

Comment: I don't think `pip` lists packages that weren't `pip install`ed

Comment: this package was pip installed look at the pip version being used in 'which pip' for verification.

Answer (score 2):

`pip freeze` is intended to produce output suitable as requirements file (usually called `requirements.txt`) to be used with `pip -r`. `pip` itself doesn't usually belong in the requirements file, so `pip freeze` omits it by default, just like it omits `setuptools` and `wheel`.

If you want these packages to be listed, too, pass the `--all` option:

```sh
pip freeze --all
```

Though, consider carefully whether you actually need `pip` in your requirements file(s). It might be better to change your approach than using `--all` to generate the files.

If you do not require an output format suitable for requirements files, you can also use `pip list` to see the versions installed in your virtualenv.

Comment: If, when re-thinking your approach, you _still_ come to the conclusion that you need `pip` in your requirements files, give us some more context on why it's needed in there.